# Keep the cursor column while swapping buffers in vim

Tags: vim

In vim, if you swap buffers with :bn and :bp, the cursor stays on the same line, but not on the same column. Is there a way to keep it on the same column as well ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:set nostartofline
```

from the help: "In case of buffer changing commands the cursor is placed at the column where it was the last time the buffer was edited."

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head I don't think so.  But Vim sets the mark " as the last position when exiting a buffer.  So typing `" will get you back to that spot.  You could try creating an auto-command to jump to that mark automatically on entering a buffer.  Try something like

```
:au BufEnter  * :normal `"
```